# To print float value upto 6 decimal without rounding off in JAVA

Tags: java

```
float sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   sum = sum+marks[i];   // marks is an integer array
}
return sum/3;
```

`marks` array has values 95, 80, 75

I want answer to be 83.333333 but compiler gives me 83.333336

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: `83.333336` is the decimal representation of the closest `float` value to 83 + 1/3.  If you want something closer, use `double`.  If you want want something closer than that, maybe `BigDecimal`.  If you want an exact representation, use a fraction; i.e print it as `"250 / 3"`

Comment: For example, if you were to compute the above using `double` and the use the formatter `new DecimalFormat("##.######")`, that would give you the number correct to 6 decimal places.  But you have to use `double`.